# Which of the following running times are polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity

This is a problem for my algorithms class that I'm still confused about.

Here are the choices:

- i. Ө(mC)
- ii. Ө((m^2)logC)
- iii. Ө(n^3)
- iv. Ө((2^n)m^2)

The answer is ii and iii. Can someone explain each choice is wrong or right? 
My initial thought would be that i,ii,iii are all correct. But from what I understand it's more based on the the bits scale. I'll also add that the inputs are **integers.**

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** If C is the input length, then the number of elements possible are 2^C, since I can construct 2^C different numbers with C bits. It seems (from our discussion below) that this is the case here. So,

(i). complexity is (m, linear) * (C, exponential) --> not polynomial

(ii). complexity is (m^2, quadratic) * (log C, linear) --> polynomial

Next time it will be helpful if you specify what the variables represent, since sometimes C is a constant overhead and not a variable input.

Comment: I think it has something do with inputs and because if you multiply by a factor of C then your actually increasing by scale 2^C because of the extra the binary factor. Does that help at all?

Comment: OK I see now -- C is the bit length or something? Is that right? C isn't a constant? If that's the case, then the length of C increases the size exponentially, but log C is linear complexity.

Comment: yes I believe that is the reasoning. can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'll update the answer, it makes a lot more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

iv) it is based off the fastest growing factor. so because iv) has 2^n it is exponential no polynomial.

i) although it is technically a polynomial, in the context of Big O notation is generally refered to as linear